# How to make the radio button checked in android while updating the form?

Tags: android, radio-group

I have an application form with one radio group that consists of two radio buttons (self delivery and company delivery). While inserting the details everything is working fine and I can get the text of radio button selected by the code below:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    // find the radiobutton by returned id
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

    if (radioButton.isChecked()) {
      OPTIONS=radioButton.getText().toString();
      if (OPTIONS.equals("SelfDelivery")) {
        deliveryAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        deliveryEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } else {
        deliveryAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deliveryEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When I press the edit button and go to edit page, I want the radio button to also be selected according to the user.
For example: If the user is selecting the company delivery (in the edit page the company delivery should be selected in the radio group).
I do not know how to get the selected id and make the radio group to be selected in the edit page.

Comment: You can pass your `OPTIONS` string in a `Bundle` to your editpage and in your editpage onCreate() get this string and check for your value and set the radion button checked according to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
 // on edit try this way
        RadioButton radioButtonSelf;
        RadioButton radioButtonCompany;
        radioButtonSelf = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selfradiobuttonid);
        radioButtonCompany = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonCompany);

        if(OPTIONS.equals("SelfDelivery")){
            radioButtonSelf.setChecked(true);
            radioButtonCompany.setChecked(false);

        }else{
            radioButtonCompany.setChecked(true);
            radioButtonSelf.setChecked(false);
        }
```